# LINQ to Entities query and Distinct on GUID

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

When I use the LINQ to Entities and then a Distinct to get unique Guids, I'm getting all GUIDs.

```
DB-Entry 1: {b3f86f18-f661-4511-a8b5-f85aa8e41b29}
DB-Entry 2: {b3f86f18-f661-4511-a8b5-f85aa8e41b29}
DB-Entry 3: {7078d941-0906-4a1b-9a27-85cfc9cf382b}
DB-Entry 4: {7387d57e-6ac5-4b3b-b7f5-833383530bb6}
```

```
using (OrderTableEntities msgcontext = new OrderTableEntities())
{
    try
    {
        var Query = from c in msgcontext.tbl_Order
                    select c.OrderGuid;

        var distinctGuids = Query.Distinct();
    }
    catch 
    {
    }
}
```

After Execution of this code-part, all 4 rows are queried. Basically I would have expected to get just
3 Entries back. What could cause this issue, that it is not possible to get the DISTINCT Guid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I assume that applying `Distinct()` to contactsQuery rather than Query is just a slip when preparing the code for posting.

If you apply the `ToString()` method to the Guids so that the query returns an `IQueryable<string>` rather than an `IQueryable<Guid>`, do you still get all 4 guids returned?

```
var contactsQuery = from c in msgcontext.tbl_Order select c.OrderGuid.ToString();

  var distinctGuids = contactsQuery.Distinct();
```